# Project Reactor: Handling fast and slow publishers

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

Consider the following code:

```
AtomicInteger counter1 = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger counter2 = new AtomicInteger();

Flux<Object> source = Flux.generate(emitter -> {
    emitter.next("item");
});

Executor executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32);
Executor executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32);

Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.merge(source).concatMap(item -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(1);
        return "1_" + counter1.incrementAndGet();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor1)));

Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.merge(source).concatMap(item -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return "2_" + counter2.incrementAndGet();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor2)));

Flux.merge(flux1, flux2).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

You can see that one publisher is 100x faster than the other one. Still, when running the code it seems that all data is printed, but there's a huge gap between the two publishers which increases overtime.

What's interesting to note is that when changing the numbers so `executer2` will have `1024` threads, and `executer1` will have only `1` thread, then still we see a gap that is getting larger and larger overtime.

My expectation was that after tweaking the thread-pools accordingly the publishers will get balanced.

1. **I'd like to achieve a balance between publishers (relative to the thread-pool sizes and processing time)**
2. What would happen if I waited long enough? In other words, is a back-pressure can occur? (Which by default I guess it's a runtime exception, right?)

I don't want to drop items nor want to have a runtime exception. Instead, as I mentioned, I'd like the system to get balanced with respect to the resources it has and the processing times - **Does the code above promise that?**

Thanks!

Comment: Two Fluxes subscribes separately to the given source. So in the end they actually consume from two independent sources. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your `Flux` objects in this example are not `ParallelFlux` objects, so they'll only ever use one thread.**

It doesn't matter if you create a scheduler that's capable of handling thousands of threads, and pass that to one of the `Flux` objects - they'll just sit there going unused, which is exactly what's happening in this example. There's no backpressure, and it won't result in an exception - it's just going as fast as it can using one thread.

If you want to make sure that the `Flux` takes full advantage of the 1024 threads available to it, then you need to call `.parallel(1024)`:

```
ParallelFlux<String> flux1 = Flux.merge(source).parallel(1).concatMap(item -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1);
    return "1_" + counter1.incrementAndGet();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor1)));

ParallelFlux<String> flux2 = Flux.merge(source).parallel(1024).concatMap(item -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return "2_" + counter2.incrementAndGet();
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor1)));
```

If you do that to your code, then you start to see results much closer to what you seem to be expecting, with `2_` sailing past `1_` despite the fact it's sleeping for 100 times as long:

```
...
2_17075
2_17076
1_863
1_864
2_17077
1_865
2_17078
2_17079
...
```

However, a word of warning:

> I'd like to achieve a balance between publishers (relative to the thread-pool sizes and processing time)

You can't pick numbers here to *balance* the outputs, at least not reliably or in any meaningful way - the thread scheduling will be completely arbitrary. If you want to do that, then you could use [this variant of the subscribe method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.function.Consumer-), allowing you to explicitly call `request()` on the subscription consumer. This then allows you to provide backpressure by only requesting as many elements as you're prepared to deal with.

Comment: I think I understand. It doesn't matter I have a large thread pool since the subscriber itself is single-threaded so it uses one of the threads from the pool and basically waits for it to finish. By the way, I understand you can't fully synchronise the work. I meant that on expectancy (If I might say) the work would be balanced. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!